# Webpack with two common chunks: one exported, one local

Tags: javascript, webpack

I would like to use Webpack in a multi-page application in such a way that some pre-determined dependencies are bundled into a "vendor" chunk and the rest of the dependencies is bundled into a "commons" chunk.

For example, assuming two entry points (effectively representing a different page each), `pageA.js` and `pageB.js` contain both this code (in EC6, processed via Babel), followed by their own code:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
import angular from 'angular';
import uitree from 'angular-ui-tree';
```

I'd like jQuery and Bootstrap to be bundled into a "vendor" chunk, and the rest (whatever that is) to be bundled into a "commons" chunk.

The objectives are:

- I would like to be able to have another separate build that would be able to rely on that same vendor chunk, without it needing to re-include the vendor libraries (I would explicitly declare that set of vendor libraries, to make it available to any sub-build that needs it).
- I would also like not to have to re-process the vendor chunk every time I make a change to a page's script.

Here is the configuration I've tried:

```
module.exports = {
    entry : {
        "vendor" : [ "jquery", "bootstrap" ],
        "pageA" : "./src/pageA.js",
        "pageB" : "./src/pageB.js"
    },
    output : {
        path : path.join(__dirname, "./dest"),
        filename : "[name].chunk.js"
    },
    module : {
        loaders : [ {
            test : /bootstrap\/js\//,
            loader : 'imports?jQuery=jquery'
        },
        /* ... Some modules for angular and CSS processing ... */

        {
            test : /\.js?$/,
            include : [ path.resolve(__dirname, "./src") ],
            loader : 'babel',
            query : {
                presets : [ 'es2015' ]
            }
        }
        /* ... Some other settings for the fonts ... */ ]
    },
    plugins : [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $ : "jquery",
            jQuery : "jquery"
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap : false,
            mangle : false,
            compress : false
        }),
        new CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name : "vendor",
            minChunks : Infinity
        }),
        new CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name : "commons",
            minChunks : 2
        })
    ]
};
```

With the configuration above, I get jQuery and Bootstrap in `vendor.chunk.js`, as required, but the `commons.chunk.js` file is almost empty, all the rest of what's commonly used by `pageA.js` and `pageB.js` is then put into `pageA.chunk.js` and `pageB.chunk.js` (effectively duplicating that code).

If I swap the order of the last two plugins, `commons.chunk.js` now contains almost everything (unless what's actually specific to `pageA.js` and `pageB.js`), and `vendor.chunk.js` is almost empty:

```
plugins : [
    // ...,
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name : "commons",
        minChunks : 2
    }),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name : "vendor",
        minChunks : Infinity
    })
]
```

Is there a way to bundle a pre-defined list of libraries (e.g. `[ "jquery", "jquery-ui", "bootstrap" ]` into one particular chunk (in such a way that it can be used by completely independent scripts) and also have another common chunk for whatever else is in commonly used between the entry points?

The aim of all this would be to be able to build a completely separate piece of code for another page later, and tell it it doesn't need to re-bundle those pre-defined libraries.

Here is a diagram representing what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Dependencies Diagram]

I would then use the generated scripts as follows on page A:

```
<script src="vendor.js"></script>
<script src="common.js"></script>
<script src="pageA.chunk.js"></script>
```

And on page C (built completely independently from pages A and B):

```
<script src="vendor.js"></script>
<script src="common2.js"></script>
<script src="pageC.chunk.js"></script>
```

(I am using Webpack 1.12.14.)

---

I have tried the solution suggested in [the only answer so far](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35775596/372643). While this makes it indeed possible to separate the vendor chunk from the commons chunk, the vendor chunks (with the same definition) made from two separate builds generally cannot be swapped between each other. This does not make it possible to use only one of those vendor chunks across two builds (even though they are virtually the same).

Answer (score 10):

I was working on something similar. I observed the behaviour you desire by having this configuration:

```
const entryPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "modules"),
    entryPoints = {
        vendor: ["babel-polyfill", "react", "react-dom", "react-pure-render", "react-simpletabs", "react-redux", "redux", "redux-thunk"],
        a: entryPath + "/a.js",
        b: entryPath + "/b.js",
        c: entryPath + "/c.js",
        d: entryPath + "/d.js",
        ...
    }, plugins = [
        new CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: "commons",
            filename: "commons.bundle.js",
            minChunks: 2,
            chunks: Object.keys(entryPoints).filter(key => key !== "vendor")
        }),
        new CommonsChunkPlugin("vendor", "vendor.bundle.js"),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].bundle.css", {
            //allChunks: true
        })
    ];
```

so this code above left in b.bundle.js still some import of React and other React libraries. after I added "fixed-data-table" to the vendor list, that disappeared and the only react source code there was was in vendor.bundle.js I assume that is what you were looking for? (in the end each vendor not listed in vendor list ended up in each own module.bundle.js or in commons.bundle.js if it was re-used in multiple bundles)

Regards
Jonas

Comment: Side note: using new CommonsChunkPlugin({name: "vendor", filename: "vendor.bundle.js", chunks: ["vendor"], minChunks: Infinity}) instead of new CommonsChunkPlugin("vendor", "vendor.bundle.js") did not work.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work in terms of separating the vendor and the commons libraries, but there's still an aspect missing (or at least I can't get it to work): being able to re-use that same `vendor.bundle.js` from a separate sub-project ("Page C" in my example). I've tried to build two subprojects like this (renaming the "vendor" and "common" output) and make one page use the other's "vendor" file, but it doesn't work. I can't seem to be able to get a vendor bundle that's usable by anything, independently of the webpack project.

Comment: @jonas.hartwig You mentioned that you added "fixed-data-table" to your vendor list to fix the issue where some of the react code showing in your common.js. Can you elaborate a little more on what you mean by adding "fixed-data-table"? Thanks!

Comment: yes, in webpack you have the entry configuration. part of that is the vendor list (a list of npm packages to be added to vendor.js if you want one): https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html

Answer (score 2):

As far as your request to be able to use the vendor chunk created in one webpack build with bundles from another build, the only way I have found to do this is through a combination of [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader) and `externals`.

In my case, I successfully used this to bundle jQuery (and Bootstrap) into a "common.js" in one build, and then use that jQuery in modules belonging to another build, as follows:

### 1. Expose jQuery from build A chunk

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      // export jQuery globals for other modules to use as externals
      test: require.resolve('jquery'),
      loader: 'expose?$!expose?jQuery'
    }
  ]
}
```

### 2. Consume jQuery in build B modules

```
externals: {
  'jquery': 'jQuery'
}
```

Of course, the drawback to this is that you're bridging between the two sets of bundles by using manually-managed global variables, which you probably started using webpack to avoid :-)

However, I don't know of any other way at this point, given that every webpack build creates its own namespace of "private" IDs internally to reference modules, with no guarantee of stability or global unique-ness.